# Finding functions from a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

During a problem I have stumbled upon a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac {1}{z-n}+\frac {1}{n})$. This is equivalent to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z}{zn-n^2}$ so I know it'll be a meromorphic function with a pole at every z=n and I think these poles will all have order 1. How do I find the function that goes to this series?

Answer (score 3):

This series does not converge at any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. It is essentially the harmonic series.

Edit: After reading the question again, I realize that you might mean the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{n}.$ This is well-defined.

Taking the digamma function $$\psi(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \Big( \mathrm{Log}\, \Gamma(z) \Big) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+z} \Big),$$ and replacing $z$ by $1-z,$ you find $$\psi(1-z) + \gamma = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n-z} \Big) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{n} \Big).$$

Comment: It was indeed thanks. I'll edit that in above.

Comment: I disagree, for instance, if $z=-1$ then this series converges to $1$.

Comment: @Leandro The question has been edited